# Torque of a rolling cylinder

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics

[image: Figure]

I would like to ask the associated net torque equation for this diagram.

[image: Force diagram]

Since the tension force is directed counterclockwise, my equation for the torque was

[image: torque]

However, the solution to the problem indicates: the tension force and friction force each exert a torque about the center of mass of the cylinder. The torque of the friction force is counterclockwise (positive), and the torque of the tension force is negative; hence, the equation for the torque is:

[image]

I am confused. Isn't tension force directed counterclockwise? Or, should the direction of angular velocity be regarded as counterclockwise and therefore positive?

::EDIT::

Other equations (used to derive a_cm) are as follows:

[image: Force]

Comment: It might be a typo for the clockwise and counterclockwise directions in the book. However, notice that either alternative is correct. It doesn't matter in which direction you choose the torque to be positive if you keep consistency for later calculations. Both alternatives will return same results with the difference of a minus sign.

Comment: @Jaime_mc2 I think so too. Thank you very much for your detailed guidance.